# Mean square convergence of number of 5s and 6s in dice throws

Tags: probability, dice

> Let $N_n$ be the number of occurrences of 5 or 6 in $n$ throws of a fair die. Show that as $n\to\infty$, 
>   $$
> \frac{1}{n}N_n\to \frac{1}{3}, \mbox{ in mean square.}
> $$

My thoughts so far:

I order to use the **Mean square law of large numbers** we need to have that the $N_i$s have the same mean and the same variance, as they are obviously independent.

Proving that they have the same mean, namely $\frac{1}{3}$ is not hard, however I do not know how to go about finding the variance. I will present the way I found the mean, maybe there is a better way of finding that as well, and to extrapolate that formula to the variance.

If we throw a die $n$ times, then there will be $6^n$ possible outcomes, each with the same probability. Hence, there will be $n\cdot 6^n$ numbers, each with the same probability. By symmetry, the number of $5$s and $6$s will be the same, hence we only need to calculate the number of $5$s.

If we fix a die as $5$ then we will have $6^{n-1}$ numbers of 5 thrown with that die fixed. Given that we have $n$ dice, the total number of $5$s will be $n6^{n-1}$

$$
E[N_n] = 2\cdot\left ( \frac{1}{6^n}\cdot (n\cdot 6^{n-1})\right ) = \frac{1}{3}
$$

How would I be able to apply this logic (or any other) in order to calculate the variance?

Answer (score 1):

Use the approach of user asdf . $E(\frac {N_n} n - \frac 1 3)^{2}= E|\frac {(X_1-\frac 1 3 )+X_2-\frac 1 3 )+...+X_n-\frac 1 3 )} n|^{2}=\frac 1 {n^{2}} n Var (X_1)= \frac 2 9 \frac 1 {n} \to 0$
.

Comment: This question is asked before they present either the CLT or the SLLN, I am assuming they would want me to find a formula for the variance, and it is also something I would be interested in finding as a problem on its own, if possible

Comment: @AndreiCrisan I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to use the Central Limit Theorem applied to $N_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$

where $X_i=1$ if the throw is $5$ or $6$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

This immediately gives $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\frac{1}{3}$, $var(X_i)=\frac{2}{9}$

Comment: He is asking for convergence in mean square, not in distribution.